# Sending an email to a manager based on a specific person

Tags: workflow

I have a calendar in SharePoint 2010 that several employees add leave and vacation time to. There are five managers that ask their employees to put time on this calendar. The managers would like to have a workflow created that will email them specifically when one of their employees modifies or adds an event to the calender.

I am not sure how to do this. If I have group A assigned to Manager A. I do not want any employee from Group B adding an event and Manager A receive a notification. It should be sequential with Group A sending an email to Manger A, Group B sending an email to Manager B, etc. Does anyone have an idea how I would go about creating this?

Answer (score 2):

In the workflow, can't you just utilize the Find Manager action to look up the user's manager?

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two ways to do this:
**Without any custom code**
Create a calendar for each group so that the managers can then manage their alerts to their own group's calendar. This also makes sure that group A only sees group A's events when looking at their calendar.

**Custom code**
You could do this as a custom workflow step but there really isn't any need for a workflow here. I would recommend creating a custom [EventReceiver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg749858%28v=office.14%29.aspx) to send the emails out when an item is added or changed.

Comment: I was hoping for something that did not require any code. I am not a developer, and I have no idea what an event receiver is. Does anyone else know of another solution that would still maintain the entire calendar, yet allow us to break a workflow into mailing a manager based on specific group members or individuals when they add events or modifications?

Comment: Sorry but I don't think there is a way to do that without some code.